# Firebase dynamic link is not working on IOS

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-dynamic-links

We have been using firebase dynamic link on android for a while.It was working fine in android.
We have decided to build our project on IOS platform also.Now we are facing some problems in dynamic link.
On pressing the link our application does not open.We also following the tutorial to integrate dynamic link on IOS.

1.Added .Plist file.

2.Added associated Domain in capabilities.(applinks:domain-link)

3.Added URL Types in info.

4.Added Team ID.

Seems like we are following the exact steps in the documentation. And yet Dynamic link is not working for us.
Can anyone help us in resolving this issue?

Answer (score 2):

check

1. [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/) enable your `Associated Domains` from your app Identifiers
2. check AASA file `team id` and `bundle id` from `https://{your set domain}.page.link/apple-app-site-association`
3. AASA effective not real time
4. open your note app input `https://xxx.page.link/ooo` test (not on browser)

I hope I can help you

Answer (score 1):

i'm using a Flutter App and on Android i can read internal link with custom parameter, however, on iOS i can not, the App is opened but onLink.listen is never called. I did all iOS platform configuration posted on documentation.

The link used to open the App looks like (Long Dynamic Link):
https://sample.page.link/?link=https://sample.page.link/test?CUSTOM_PARAM=fooBar&apn=br.com.test&isi=12345&ibi=br.com.test

The idea is to use only one dynamic link and pass dynamic data as custom parameter. Did anyone face that problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem and i want help you. Firebase was setup in my project already.
I use Unity and build app on android and ios. Android is work, but ios is big problem.
You should check this:

1. add associated domain:

   ```
        private static void AddAssociatedDomains(string path)
    {
        //This is the default path to the default pbxproj file. Yours might be different
        string projectPath = "/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj";
        //Default target name. Yours might be different
        string targetName = "Unity-iPhone";
        //Set the entitlements file name to what you want but make sure it has this extension
        string entitlementsFileName = "my_app.entitlements";
        var entitlements = new ProjectCapabilityManager(path + projectPath, entitlementsFileName, targetName);
        entitlements.AddAssociatedDomains(new string[] { "applinks:example.com/link" });
        //Apply
        entitlements.WriteToFile();
    }
   ```

your domain's place in firebase console - dynamic links - left top corner blue font. whithout https:/// path in method is path of "Info.plist"

2. this have to been in info.plist

> ```
> <key>FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains</key>
> <array>
> <string>https://example.com/link</string>
> </array>
> ```

in Unity you can do this in this way:

```
        private static void AddFirebaseDynamicLincsInfo(PlistDocument plist)
    {
        var customDomains = plist.root.CreateArray("FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains");
        customDomains.AddString("https://example.com/link>");
    }
```

3. if you use appsflyer, it is problem) they are conflicted. You should find file AppsFlyerAppController.mm in your unity project and paste this string

> ```
> [super application:application continueUserActivity:userActivity restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
> ```

It must like be this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))restorationHandler {
    [super application:application continueUserActivity:userActivity restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
    [[AppsFlyerAttribution shared] continueUserActivity:userActivity restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your AppDelegate.m file as well. Follow from steps 4 mentioned in the section **Open Dynamic Links in your app** [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive#open-dynamic-links-in-your-app)

Answer (score 0):

please cross check associated domains : (it must not contain http or https e.g. applinks:myapp.page.link ) .and Dynamic link is easily work on iOS Simulator , I don't get any issues.

And if you creating dynamic link from firebase ios sdk then below code will be useful

```
 guard let link = URL(string: "Write your link here and parameters") else { return }
    let dynamicLinksDomainURIPrefix = "https://racematesios.page.link" //domain-link
    let linkBuilder = DynamicLinkComponents(link: link, domainURIPrefix: dynamicLinksDomainURIPrefix )

    linkBuilder!.iOSParameters = DynamicLinkIOSParameters(bundleID: "Bundle ID")
    linkBuilder!.iOSParameters?.appStoreID = "App store ID"

    guard let longDynamicLink = linkBuilder?.url else { return }
    print("The long URL is: \(longDynamicLink)")
```